# Выравнивание элементов в flex-container

Tags: html, css, css3, html5

Есть flex-container с элементами внутри, при последовательной вставки каждого элемента они выстраиваются вслед за другом по главной оси, но при переносе нового элемента на следующую строку элемент становится в центр(как на картинке). Как можно сделать, чтобы элемент под номером 7 был ровно под элементом 1 ?

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Css код, что использую.

```html
<style type="text/css">
.flex-container {
    display: flex;
    flex-wrap: wrap;
    flex-direction: row column; 
    justify-content: center;
}
</style>
```

Comment: убрать `justify-content: center;`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Для этого нужно сменить

```
justify-content: center;
```

на

```
justify-content: flex-start;
```

```css
.flex-container {
    display: flex;
    flex-wrap: wrap;
    flex-direction: row column; 
    justify-content: flex-start;
}
.element{
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  background: red;
  border: 1px solid green;
}
```

```html
<div class="flex-container">
  <div class="element"></div>
  <div class="element"></div>
  <div class="element"></div>
  <div class="element"></div>
  <div class="element"></div>
  <div class="element"></div>
</div>
```